# Как поменять ориентацию RecyclerView во время выполнения

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Пытаюсь изменить ориентацию на recyclerview во время выполнения по событию onScrolled. Ниже привожу метод onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(totalItemCount));

    // default orientation is VERTICAL
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, spanCount, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            Log.i("TAG", "current orientation: " + gridLayoutManager.getOrientation());

            if (dx > 0) {
                Log.i("TAG", "dx = " + dx);
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
                    }
                });

            } else if (dy > 0) {
                Log.i("TAG", "dy = " + dy);
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    }
                });
            }
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
    };

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(listener);
}
```

Данный код выполняется без ошибок но и ориентация не меняется. Возможно ли как то поменять ориентацию во время выполнения? Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё вызвать `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()` не помогло ((